# javascript: change CSS position by relative amount

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

Basically what I'm trying to do is every time the JavaScript is executed (by click), the CSS `left` value for my `<div>` descreases by 20%. So, for example, `left` starts at 40%. The first time you click it should become 20%, and then 0%, and then -20%, and so on. I've updated my code below:

```
FilmstripLeft = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(ul).left, 10) / 4;
ul.style.left = (FilmstripLeft - 20) + "%";
```

`ul` is a `<div>` I get using `document.getElementById()`. This code works now, but I'm unsure about the divided by 4 at the end of the first line. I tested than that line was returning a value of 160 before I added the `/ 4` at the end, even though the starting value is 40%. I'm not sure if this is because it's returning the value in pixels instead of percent, in which case dividing by 4 would only work if `left` is at `160px`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "left" value for my div descreases by 20%

No. According to your explanation, you want to decrease it by 20 [percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point), not by 20%.

> `getComputedStyle(ul).left`

Be aware percentages are relative units. When computed, they are transformed to an absolute length.

You can only access the raw percentage as an inline style

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
  target.style.left = parseFloat(target.style.left) - 20 + '%';
});
```

```css
#target {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" style="left: 80%"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click" />
```

But you don't need the raw percentage in order to subtract 20 percentage points. You can use `calc`:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var current = getComputedStyle(target).left;
  target.style.left = 'calc(' + current + ' - 20%)';
});
```

```css
#target {
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click" />
```

Comment: The calc code worked perfectly, thanks. I didn't realize the difference between percent and pecentage points before, thanks for pointing that out too.

Answer (score 0):

`getComputedStyle()` won't work well for your purposes because it, by definition, returns the *computed* value of the style in terms of pixels, not the relative percentage of the original value. In order to calculate what "20%" is using computed styles, you will have to do it manually by finding the parent element's width and then taking 20% of that:

```js
function onClick(){
  var myElement = document.getElementById("inner");
  var leftValue = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(myElement).left);
  
  var parentElement = myElement.parentElement;
  var parentWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(parentElement).width);
  var twentyPercent = parentWidth * 0.20;
  
  var newLeftValue = (leftValue - twentyPercent) + "px";
  
  myElement.style.left = newLeftValue;
  updateStatus();
}

function updateStatus(){
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("inner")).left; 
}

updateStatus();
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #888;
}

#inner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

The downside of this method is that it fixes `left` as a pixel value instead of a true percentage of the parent, so if the window/parent width changes, the `left` value won't match properly.

It's easier if the `left` value is an inline HTML style instead of a CSS style because you can get it directly with `element.style`, which reads the inline HTML style value. Then you can assign a new `left` value as a true percentage that will update if the window/parent width changes.

```js
function onClick(){
  var myElement = document.getElementById("inner");
  // Note how #inner's left value is now inline instead of CSS
  var leftValue = parseFloat(myElement.style.left);
  
  var newLeftValue = (leftValue - 20) + "%";
  
  myElement.style.left = newLeftValue;
  updateStatus();
}

function updateStatus(){
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inner").style.left; 
}

updateStatus();
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #888;
}

#inner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner" style="left: 80%"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">click me</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

So, if possible, put your styles inline instead of into CSS because they're easier to access. Technically it is possible to access CSS stylesheet rules using JavaScript but it is *very* convoluted and I don't recommend it if you're new to web development.